# How to call a mysql stored procedure, with arguments, from command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line, call, procedure

How can I call a stored procedure from command line?

I have a procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertEvent`(IN `dateTimeIN` DATETIME)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    SET @eventIDOut = NULL;

    IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `eventDate` = dateTimeIN) THEN
        SELECT `eID` INTO @eventIDOut FROM `events` WHERE `eventDate` = dateTimeIN LIMIT 1;
        ELSE
        INSERT INTO `events` (`eventDate`) VALUES(dateTimeIN);
        SET @eventIDOut = last_insert_id();
    END IF;

    SELECT CONCAT(@eventIDOut);
END
```

1. **I tried this:** `mysql> CALL insertEvent(2012.01.01 12:12:12);`

   **Result:**

   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
   syntax to use near '.01 12:12:12)' at line 1
2. **And this:** `mysql> CALL insertEvent`

   `-> 2012.01.01 12:12:12;`

   **Result:**

   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2012.01.01 12:12:12' at line 2

Answer (score 112, accepted):

With quotes around the date:

```
mysql> CALL insertEvent('2012.01.01 12:12:12');
```